# Error trying to start Oracle 12c on Solaris 11

Tags: oracle, solaris, oracle12c

After the installation of Oracle 12c under Solaris 11 .. Im running SQLPlus and after typing startup i get this error :

```
SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/initDB12C.ora'
```

Any ideas guys ? i've tried everything i found on the net

.profile File

```
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=solaris; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.1.0.2/db_1; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=DB12C; export ORACLE_SID
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$CRS_HOME/lib
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
```

init.ora File :

```
# Change '<ORACLE_BASE>' to point to the oracle base (the one you specify at    
# install time)            
db_name='ORCL'    
memory_target=1G    
processes = 150    
audit_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/admin/orcl/adump'    
audit_trail ='db'    
db_block_size=8192    
db_domain=''    
db_recovery_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/fast_recovery_area'    
db_recovery_file_dest_size=2G    
diagnostic_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>'    
dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLXDB)'    
open_cursors=300     
remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'    
undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'    
# You may want to ensure that control files are created on separate physical    
# devices    
control_files = (ora_control1, ora_control2)    
compatible ='11.2.0'
```

Comment: Is your `ORACLE_SID` correct? Does `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/initDB12C.ora` exist, or is it probably something like `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/initDB12c.ora` (lowercase 'c')?

Comment: the only file i have is init.ora

Comment: @AndreasFester this is what i have : 
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/init.ora

Comment: The init file usually contains the SID as part of its filename, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39812/oracle-database-uses-wrong-parameter-file You could try to rename/copy `init.ora` to `initDB12C.ora`, but probably something else went wrong during installation, so other issues could occur then ...

Comment: @AndreasFester check the question .. i posted the init.ora

Comment: @AndreasFester .. I tried to start the oracle with init.ora and i got this message : 

ORA-01261: Parameter db_recovery_file_dest destination string cannot be translated
ORA-01262: Stat failed on a file destination directory
Solaris-AMD64 Error: 2: No such file or directory

I tried to create the destination but no luck .. same problem

Comment: I see that you posted the contents of the init.ora file. That's fine, but avoids the fact that what was specified during the DB installation was a file called `initDB12C.ora` - *not* `init.ora`. You can either rename the file to match what the db instance expects, or symlink it to the correct name. The content of the file isn't the issue here.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson Thanks sir; the problem has been resolved ..